# C# Error - Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to save the incoming photo to the folder. I want to save the names as Guids so that there is no problem when a file with the same name comes in, but there seems to be an error in my code. I didn't use a guid and I don't know how to use it.

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<SliderResponse>> Handle(SliderCreate request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(request.file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)request.file.OpenReadStream().Length);
        }

        Guid ImageFileName = new Guid ((request.file.FileName).ToString());
        var FileContentType = request.file.ContentType;
        var ImageContent = bytes;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\File";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            using (var fs = new FileStream(path+ @"\" + ImageFileName , FileMode.Create ))
            {
                ms.WriteTo(fs);
            }
        }

        var mapped = _mapper.Map<Slider>(request);

        if (mapped == null)
            return new ErrorApiResponse<SliderResponse>(ResultMessage.NotCreatedSlider);

        var model = await _repo.Sliders.AddAsync(mapped);

        var response = _mapper.Map<SliderResponse>(model);

        return new SuccessApiResponse<SliderResponse>(response);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot just convert an arbitrary string to a Guid, it has to be of a specific format. But even if you could, it would not solve your problem to create a unique identification even if the file name is not unique. You might think of constructing a hash over the data instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
Guid ImageFileName = new Guid ((request.file.FileName).ToString());
```

(because the string you pass into a Guid constructor should be a string that represents a Guid - it is similar to Guid.Parse. Don't pass a string that is not representative of a Guid, like "IMG_0123.JPG" your user just uploaded - this image file name does not represent a guid)

Change

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path+ @"\" + ImageFileName , FileMode.Create ))
```

To

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) , FileMode.Create ))
```

Use Path.Combine to combine paths. It understands the different directory separator chars of the system it is running on. If you hard code a windows backslash and then run your apps on Linux, you'll get a surprise.. Path.Combine takes N number of arguments and builds them into a path. Check out the other methods available in Path- some handy stuff in there

---

If you want the file to have an extension, maybe pull it off the request filename with `Path.GetExtension(request.file.FileName)` and add it to the Guid string like `Path.Combine(path, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}{Path.GetExtension(request.file.FileName)}")`

You also don't need to check if a directory exists before you call CreateDirectory- calling CreateDirectory on a dir that exists is a non-op

Comment: I tried it and it partially works. It saves as a guid, but the file is empty, so the name of the photo changes, but the photo does not come.

Comment: That's not related to the current question; you should ask a new question. The problem of "why do I get this exception about Guid format xxxx" is resolved. It's no problem to ask a new question and on SO we should not start off asking about 1 thing and then keep changing the question over and over ("oh, now the file is empty", "oh now the file isn't saved to the database", "oh, now the image isn't appearing in the thumbnail on the webpage..") until we have debugged our entire app..